# Titanium Appcelerator Final Package Build Crash (Log Included)

Tags: iphone, build, crash, titanium

I'm running into a problem with my final iPhone app build before I send it off to the App Store for approval. This is the first app I've built.

The app sometimes crashes on the actual device I'm testing with (an iPod Touch 2nd G, which is all I have at my disposal), but never in the iPhone simulator. Titanium Developer doesn't spit out any other errors either.

Here's the build/iphone/build/build.log file:

```
Starting build at 06/15/11 08:32

Build details:

timestamp=04/18/11 17:16
version=1.6.2
githash=878906d


Script arguments:
/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.2/iphone/builder.py
distribute
"4.2"
"/Users/tfontaine/Desktop/MAMP testing/APPS/my_app"
com.example.fest2011
"MYAPP"
##EDITED OUT PROVISIONING NUMBER##
"null"
"/Users/tfontaine/Downloads"
iphone

Building from: /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.2/iphone
Platform: Darwin Kernel Version 10.6.0: Wed Nov 10 18:13:17 PST 2010; root:xnu-1504.9.26~3/RELEASE_I386

Xcode path is: /Developer


Exception detected in script:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.2/iphone/builder.py", line 664, in main
provisioning_profile = read_provisioning_profile(pp,o)
File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.2/iphone/builder.py", line 216, in read_provisioning_profile
f = open(f,'rb').read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/Users/tfontaine/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/##EDITED OUT PROVISIONING NUMBER##.mobileprovision'
```

Does this have something to do with acquiring the proper distribution keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time I get that error is when the provisioning profile is missing or not hooked up properly to a certificate in my keychain. Have you tried this in [TiStudio](http://my.appcelerator.com) instead of TiDeveloper?